# Extending JPanel or returning JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, 2d-games

I'm currently trying to recreate Breakout and was wondering how to implement basic gui. My structure is a JFrame that contains a JPanel and the JPanel is what actually hold the game's elements. The JFrame gets this JPanel by adding it to it's content pane [frame.getContentPane().add(myPanel)].

My question is, should the class that holds the game's elements extend JPanel or simply return a JPanel?

```
public class myPanel {
    private JPanel panel;
    public myPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        //do stuff with the panel
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}

public class myPanel extends JPanel{
    public myPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        //do stuff with the panel
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any methods of `JPanel` that you intend to override ?

Comment: If you plan on drawing directly in the JPanel, you should subclass since you will probably want to override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to do draw your custom stuff

Comment: It seems that extending Swing components is a common thing but does not make sense unless you are trying to override a method (as mentioned here). My preference is to never extend components (including window components like JFrame or JDIalog) unless you need to override a method or create a custom swing component that extends JComponent.

Answer (score 0):

you should definetely use extend in most cases I believe.
And also this is wrong:

```
public class myPanel extends JPanel{
    public myPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        //do stuff with the panel
    }
}
```

It should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    myPanel panel=new myPanel("hello");
    frame.add(panel);
    System.out.println(panel.getHello());
}

public class myPanel extends JPanel{
    String hello;
    //stuff you need in the panel
    public myPanel(String hello) {
        this.hello=hello;
    }
    public String getHello(){
        return hello;
    }
}
```

A reason you should do this is to easily @override the paint(), and handle the things you need for the JPanel inside it.
If you want to keep things simple and don't need to override anything you might not need to extend, but I would not consider creating a class just to hold the JPanel an option.